# Converting xml into dataframe

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, elementtree

I'm trying to convert my xml-request (see example below) into a pandas-dataframe, but it doesn't work the way it should and I'm not sure why.

**Example xml-request**

```
<workingTimes>
<day>
    <date>2015-09-21</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Mon</dayOfWeek>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Albert</firstName>
        <lastName>Grimaldi</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Max</firstName>
        <lastName>Mustermann</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber>12346</personnelNumber>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
</day>
<day>
    <date>2015-09-22</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Tue</dayOfWeek>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Albert</firstName>
        <lastName>Grimaldi</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Max</firstName>
        <lastName>Mustermann</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber>12346</personnelNumber>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
</day>
</workingTimes>
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
...
r = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

root = et.fromstring(r.content)

df_cols, rows = ['date', 'dayOfWeek', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'duration', 'costCenter'], []
for child in root:
    s_date = child.attrib.get("date")
    s_dayOfWeek = child.attrib.get("dayOfWeek")
    s_firstName = child.find("firstName").text if child is not None else None
    s_lastName = child.find("lastName").text if child is not None else None
    s_duration= child.find("duration").duration if child is not None else None
    s_costCenter= child.find("costCenter").text if child is not None else None

    rows.append({'date': s_date, 'dayOfWeek': s_dayOfWeek, 'firstName': s_firstName, 'lastName': 
        s_lastName, 'duration': s_duration, 's_costCenter': costCenter})

df_xml = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
```

And this is a part of the documentary:[image: API Documentary]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? Note that  `date` and `dayOfWeek` are not  at the same level as the rest if the properties you are looking for.

Comment: @balderman I'm getting an empty dataframe, even though I know there are entrys in my xml! It's like I'm unable to get into the subelement (is it called that way?).

Comment: start by testing the code I have posted and populate the df. If it works - extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see below (just extend the code in order to collect more elements)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML = '''<workingTimes>
<day>
    <date>2015-09-21</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Mon</dayOfWeek>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Albert</firstName>
        <lastName>Grimaldi</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Max</firstName>
        <lastName>Mustermann</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber>12346</personnelNumber>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
</day>
<day>
    <date>2015-09-22</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Tue</dayOfWeek>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Albert</firstName>
        <lastName>Grimaldi</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Max</firstName>
        <lastName>Mustermann</lastName>
        <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <personnelNumber>12346</personnelNumber>
        <duration>00:00:00</duration>
        <rest mandatory="00:00:00">00:00:00</rest>
        <costCenter>AB-1234</costCenter>
    </employee>
</day>
</workingTimes>'''
data = []
root = ET.fromstring(XML)
days = root.findall('.//day')
for d in days:
    emp_lst = d.findall('employee')
    for e in emp_lst:
        # TODO collect more data
        data.append(
            {'day': d.find('date').text, 'first_name': e.find('firstName').text, 'last_name': e.find('lastName').text})
for entry in data:
    print(entry)
```

output

```
{'day': '2015-09-21', 'first_name': 'Albert', 'last_name': 'Grimaldi'}
{'day': '2015-09-21', 'first_name': 'Max', 'last_name': 'Mustermann'}
{'day': '2015-09-22', 'first_name': 'Albert', 'last_name': 'Grimaldi'}
{'day': '2015-09-22', 'first_name': 'Max', 'last_name': 'Mustermann'}
```